# How can I ignore the exception if the item is not found? Selenium(selenide)

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

Several of my tests refer to importBrokerCheckBox. But not all tests have to find it, because he must be absent. That is, if the element is on the page, then we must click on it, and if it is not there, we must go further through the code.But below code doesn't work and throws exception - xpath not found

```
importBrokerCheckBox = $x(".//div[text()='Брокер']/../../../preceding-sibling::span//span[@aria-label=\"caret-down\"]"),

    if (importBrokerCheckBox.isDisplayed());
    {
        importBrokerCheckBox.click();
    }

    if (importBrokerSettingsCheckbox.isDisplayed());
    {
        importBrokerSettingsCheckbox.click();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two options:

1. try/catch block - if element is not found (`NoSuchElementException` occured) the catch block code is executed (can be empty ofc).
2. using `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.by);` if no element is found, `NoSuchElementException` is NOT thrown and the list stays empty like `new ArrayList<WebElement>()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to catch selenide exception by catching general class Exception because it extends from Error :O

```
try {
...
} catch (com.codeborne.selenide.ex.ElementNotFound e) {
```

(See [Cannot catch NoSuchElementException with Selenide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52494750/381083))